# Resolving <asset/> links to assets using their absolute URL

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin

In a grails application, I want to use the absolute url to resolve an asset in a grails application, but unlike the *absolute* attribute for * and , the asset pipeline does not have a way to resolve assets using an absolute link resolved by *grails.serverURL*.

Anyone can tell me of an alternative with is not by using the resources plugin?

Comment: [assetPath does.](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/ref/Tags/assetPath.html)

Comment: Thanks, also found out there as a configuration that helps resolve assets,

http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html **Mappings and Asset Taglib URLs**